# Most efficient way to store and retrieve data

Tags: java, android, performance, hashmap

What is the best way to store data permanently in the code? I have the data e.g.
Roll No. (Unique Key)
Values: Name, DOB, Weight, Height etc.

These are going to be static information and I want to store them as the part of application. While using, I want to load them in hashmap so that I can quickly access any student based on the key (Roll number). The data size can go up to 100K entries.

I tried with enum, e.g.

```
2015CSE3245(“John”, “1997-08-13”, “73”, “176”);
```

Is this the best and most efficient way to store the data? Is there any better way in terms of memory and time to read?

Comment: So every time a new student is enrolled you are going to release a new version of your app? Sounds like a good way to create a steady stream of income (or none at all).

Comment: @peit.t This is just an example. Its for storing the data which is not likely to change at all.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would store the data in standard database SQLite which is supported by Android out of box. There are various ORM frameworks that improve read/write performance with SQLite databases. Create student class and just store them in standard HashMap.

Is there any reason why you have to store all 100k instances in memory at the same time? Would be better to load when necessary one by one or in groups of 20-50.